# .NET StateServer - Application will not run without it

Tags: .net, iis, session-state

so during a release to production yesterday we restarted our state server and started getting 500 errors on our site until the state server came back online.

The only page on our site that uses session is a BotDetect assembly for captcha.  All other pages were also failing.

So I decided to recreate in dev (which normally uses InProc)

1. I set the dev environment to use a local state server
2. I stopped the state server service and I got the same errors
3. Oddly - I am not even able to request a text file (test.txt) from the route of the application without getting the same error.

It seems odd that the entire application should go down because the state server is unavailable - surely it should run until someone accesses the session?

Any ideas, here is the error I receive, even if I request a text file or an image:

```
Unable to make the session state request to the session state server. Please ensure that the ASP.NET State service is started and that the client and server ports are the same.
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have found the culprit.

It turns out that there is a class in the solution that uses the Session State and that is what was causing the crash.

What lead me down a rabbit hole was my tests crashing for a .txt file.

Turns out this was being caused by the fact we use RequestReduce and have the following setting in web.config

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

which was causing text and images to go through .NET and causing some session dependent code to run.